# SemWeb - Convert C# object into RDF triples

Tags: c#, rdf, ontology, triples, semweb

All i want is to convert a C# class instance into rdf triples using semweb, in order to fill my ontology with data. My class consists of both primitive properties and other classes and i have constructed an ontology with the same structure.
e.g.

```
class Place{

string name;
Image  pic;

}
```

Is there any resource that could help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a very open-ended question.. you need to be more specific! How does your object look like? Is it a single object or an object graph? How is your ontology define? etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use C# reflection in order to investigate the properties and classes of the instance you want to convert and use the:

```
store.Add( new Statement( subject, predicate, object )
```

in order to write the triples you want as very well documented in the [SemWeb Documentation](http://razor.occams.info/code/semweb/semweb-current/doc/index.html)

Answer (score 3):

You do realize that SemWeb is abandon-ware and hasn't received a new release in almost 3 years right?  If you really want to use SemWeb then take a look at [LinqToRdf](http://code.google.com/p/linqtordf/) which is even more adandonware (last release 4 and a half years ago) but provides an ORM style layer to convert C# classes to and from RDF using attribute based annotations.

For some more recent and actively maintained alternatives see either [BrightStarDB](http://www.brightstardb.com) or [RomanticWeb](https://bitbucket.org/romanticweb/romanticweb), BrightstarDB is the more mature solution in this space.

If you prefer to roll your own solution you could look at [dotNetRDF](http://www.dotnetrdf.org) (*disclaimer - I develop this*) which is the library used as the basis for [BrightStarDB](http://www.brightstardb.com) and [RomanticWeb](https://bitbucket.org/romanticweb/romanticweb).

Comment: I would also like to support reasoning in my project thats why i am developing with semweb is there a solution for that too? sorry but i am new in this field..

Answer (score 0):

When I worked with rdf data I created 3 **URI** nodes 
 n1, n2, n3. 
Then, 
`Triple t = new Triple(n1, n2, n3);` 
`IGraph g = new Graph();`

`g.Assert(t);` 
`store.Add(g);`

I hope this will help you.